# How to deploy an ASP.NET application to localhost using IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an *ASP.NET* application to localhost using *IIS*, I've been reading a LOT of tutorials and following them step by step but I just can't seem to make it work...

I created an *Application Pool*(TestPool) with *.NET version 4.0* and gave it every permission to the folder where the application is at.

I then added an application to the *Default Web Site* and tried to run it at

> http://localhost/TestApplication/

But I keep getting:

[image: Error Image]

Any idea what is wrong and how can I solve this?

Versions:

- IIS version: 6.2
- OS: Windows 8.1
- VS 2013 Ultimate: 12.0
- VS .NET: 4.6

PS: It's my first attempt at deploying an *ASP.NET* application so if you need any further information just leave a comment.

**EDIT:**

It is now running at least thanks to Julian and Marge, but when I run it using VS it has the default view, why isn't it showing when I run it through IIS? When running through IIS it just lists the files:

[image: Files list]

Comment: put a index.html in that directory and see what happens. What is the name of your asp ? -> call http://localhost/Test/Application/MyGreatProgram.aspx or perhaps enable directory browsing which files are there for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because your website, in the IIS Server, does not have the Directory Browsing enabled and the default document (default page of the site ex: Default.aspx) configured.

Go to IIS Server IIS > Default Documents and check if the default page of your site is listed, if no, add the page.

Check the related link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942062

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you do not need to access IIS manager at all to run your webpage on localhost. All what you need to do is **right click** on the project and then choose **properties**. In the **Web** tab you will find **Servers** section. Make sure the **Project Url** is something like **http://localhost/myproj** or simply **http://localhost/** then hit **Create Virtual Directory**. Your webpage should be up by then, and you can access it either in debug mode, or simply by navigating your browser to the **Project Url** you have chosen.

Comment: What I want to do is be able to take my project (copy files to a pen) and make it run on a computer with no Visual Studio.

Comment: One of the things to make sure of when you get 403 is that your application is somewhere where IIS can access it. Do not place it in the Users folder for instance

Comment: For test purposes it's at C:\TestDeploy

Answer (score 0):

When you add web application in IIS ex.

[image]

That your hostname should be to add in host file which is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"\hosts

ex.

127.0.0.1       test.pln